# One Way Anova or two Way Anova

Tags: anova

I have a measurement Y, with 2 factors(A,B).

For A, I have two levels: A1, and A2.

For B, I have 3 levels: B1,B2 and B3.

All together, I have 4 groups:

group1: A1+B1

group2: A2+B1

group3: A2+B2

group4: A2+B3

My intended comparisons are group2 vs group1 to check the effect of factor A on B1; group3 vs group2, and group4 vs group3 to check the effect of factor B on A2.

What kind of test should I use?
I tried to use ONE-WAY ANOVA, with 3 comparisons and sidak post-hoc test.

Could I use Y~ A +B, and make contrast matrix based on the 3 comparisons? Which stat method is better?

Best regards,

Comment: So you have no observations with A1+B2 nor A1+B3?

Comment: No. I only have these 4 groups.

Comment: In that case I'd personally use one four-level predictor variable (with the combinations you specified as the levels).

Comment: Thanks very much!@Sointu Yes. I will use one four-level predictor variable, with specific contrast matrix, and p adjust methods. MANY THANKS